# Substract a year from date values on a new column

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a macro to take date values from cell J4 to the last row with value on the column and place new values on L4:L with a year substracted from the value on column J of the same row.

The code for this step that i have is:

```
Private Sub Update_Click() 
Dim inputWS1 As Worksheet
Set inputWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Universal")

lastRowUniversal = inputWS1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

inputWS1.Range("L4:L" & lastRowUniversal).Value = Evaluate("=IF(ISNUMBER(J4:J" & lastRowUniversal & "),DATE(YEAR(J4:J" & lastRowUniversal & ")-1,MONTH(J4:J" & lastRowUniversal & "),DAY(J4:J" & lastRowUniversal & ")),J4:J" & lastRowUniversal & ")")
```

`

The macro goes thru however values on L4:L show "1/0/1900". So i know the *lastrow* variable is working, because it only runs til the last row where J4 ends.

Can you guys help me correct this so if value on J4 is 02/01/2017 it shows 02/01/2016 on L4?

Thanks!

Comment: i have the Application.ScreenUpdating set on it as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two forms of Evaluate:

- Application (default) - uses the scope of the `ActiveSheet`: that may not be the sheet you expect/want.
- Worksheet (needs to be qualified with a worksheet object) - operates using the scope of the qualifying worksheet

You should use the worksheet form or you may get unexpected results.

This worked for me:

```
Sub Tester()

    Const dtFORM As String = "=IF(ISNUMBER(J4:J<r>),DATE(YEAR(J4:J<r>)-1," & _
                             "MONTH(J4:J<r>),DAY(J4:J<r>)),J4:J<r>)"

    Dim inputWS1 As Worksheet, lastRowUniversal

    Set inputWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Universal")

    lastRowUniversal = inputWS1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    '### use the *worksheet* form of Evaluate ###
    inputWS1.Range("L4:L" & lastRowUniversal).Value = _
                 inputWS1.Evaluate(Replace(dtFORM, "<r>", lastRowUniversal))

End Sub
```

Comment: This one worked great for me as i am using the worksheet form! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected.

You get 1/0/1900 because the corresponding cell in column J might be blank.
Try it like this...

```
Dim lastRowUniversal As Long
Dim inputWS1 As Worksheet
Set inputWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Universal")

lastRowUniversal = inputWS1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

inputWS1.Range("L4:L" & lastRowUniversal).Value = Evaluate("=IF(ISNUMBER(J4:J" & lastRowUniversal & "),DATE(YEAR(J4:J" & lastRowUniversal & ")-1,MONTH(J4:J" & lastRowUniversal & "),DAY(J4:J" & lastRowUniversal & ")),J4:J" & lastRowUniversal & ")")
inputWS1.Range("L4:L" & lastRowUniversal).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy;;"
```

Comment: It works as long as the worksheet "Universal" is the active sheet.

Comment: That's true since the formula used is not qualified with the sheet reference.